# Django registering users against a list of existing usernames

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django rest framework to build my application backend. I have used Django-rest-auth (https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) to enable login and registration for my app. It is already working.

However as per my new requirement, I have a list of usernames and only those usernames can register into my system. How can I achieve this?

I had few ideas (do not know if they make total sense): 
1. A new model to store usernames, so that in future more usernames can be added via admin interface
2. Whenever a user makes a call from client: the entered username is checked against this new usernames table and if it exists in the table registration is allowed.

Or there can be a still easier way to do this? Any code snippets?

Comment: Just wondering if this is a public facing project, how then would you verify the correct person is entering a username? If you were using email address or phone number as username, then a flow that included email or phone verification would be welcome.

Comment: What you say is correct, however I have it as a requirement and I am supposed to do it that way! We have a limited number of preselected users.

Comment: An easy option would be to create the users with the preselected usernames and use set_password with None (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) or use set_unusable_password and modify the signup to just set the password instead of creating a new User.

Comment: The second suggestion sounds nice, can you perhaps also provide some code snippet for signup modification without creating a user?